# ASP.NET MVC view manipulated model data immediately

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a model which is bound to a view. I want to view the manipulated data immediately without Javascript or postback. Is this possible?

In "current count" below it always shows zero.

My model:

```
public class CounterModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

My view (`Counter.cshtml`):

```
@model CounterModel

<h4>Counter</h4>

<p role="status">Current count: @Model.Number</p>

<input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="Number" />
```

My controller (`HomeController.cs`):

```
public IActionResult Counter()
{
    CounterModel model = new() { Number = 0 };

    return View(model);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So you want to update the 'current counter' with the value of what you enter in the input below?

Comment: @Olaf yes. I thought that due to the binding model this will show the value immetiately like blazor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC framework only returns HTML and provides no interactivity between the data models and the UI, without javascript / POSTs etc.

If you're looking for a framework that does provide this and allows you make bindings between UI elements and models, look into Blazor.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/intro